# Is the probability of getting these numbers of heads the same?

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-distribution

**Problem**

A fair coin ($P(H) = P(T) = 0.5$) is independently tossed $400$ times.

Is it correct to say that the probability of getting from $0$ to $160$ heads is the same as the probability of getting from $240$ to $400$ heads?

On the one hand, the answer seems 'no' because the number of heads are different.

On the other hand, if we take the first numbers of heads, from $0$ to $160$, it means that at the same time I want from $240$ to $400$ tails and because the coin is fair, it is the same probability as in the second case with $240$ to $400$ heads.

So is my initial statement correct?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, that's the same.  By symmetry, the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads is the same as getting exactly $400-k$ Heads. Numerically,  $\binom {400}k=\binom {400}{400-k}$.

Comment: @lulu But that won't hold if the coin was not fair, right?

Comment: Of course not.  This is very much dependent upon $p_H=p_T$.